# Postgresql - Error: Could not create log file /var/log/postgresql/...

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Every time I try to start postgresql, I get this error:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.2 database server                                       
* Error: Could not create log file /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log
```

To start the server, I have to sudo mkdir the postgresql folder in /var/log/

How can I start postgresql automatically every time I boot up? I already have a postgres user on the Ubuntu 12.10 system.

Comment: It looks like your `/var/log/postgresql` directory is wiped out at each reboot, which is unusual and not standard. Maybe /var/log is mounted on temporary storage or there's a custom script doing `rm -rf /var/log/*` or some such thing.

Comment: That was it. It was getting wiped from the tmpfs.

Answer (score 2):

Change the owner of the `/var/log/postgresql` directory to the postgres user:

```
chown postgres /var/log/postgresql
```

Comment: I just tried that, but the server still doesn't start at boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a .deb installation of Postgresql, it should be starting on boot up. However, since you're using a non-default Postgresql version -as I assume because Ubuntu 12.10 comes with 9.1.6-, probably  it's not booting because of a non-compatible configuration. It's just a supposition.

Have a look at `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/start.conf`, which should have the value `auto` to tell Ubuntu to start Postgresql on boot. (That file has fair simple docs about what each setting does).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a file names 'postgresql' in that folder (have no idea why/when it was created). 
rm the File solved the conflict

Answer (score 0):

> I solved it creating a "log" dir on my Freshly initiated Database data
>   dir

```
mkdir /data/MasterDB/log
chown postgres:postgres /data/MasterDB/log

[root@Test-DB postgresql]# find / -name "postgresql-Wed.log"
/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log/postgresql-Wed.log
/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/log/postgresql-Wed.log
/data/MasterDB.old/pg_log/postgresql-Wed.log
/data/MasterDB/log/postgresql-Wed.log <- This is the right log file now
[root@Test-DB postgresql]#
```

hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

** SOLUTION**

It turns out I had included the /var/log/ folder in the tmpfs to be wiped every time I reboot, since I mounted the cache and temp in RAM to speed things up.

Comment: That's generally a bad idea; you'll find that if there's no regular fsync activity and you have a reasonably high dirty writeback threshold you won't actually gain tons from putting parts of `/var` in a tmpfs or ramdisk. It's also just not good sysadmin - the data is in `/var` not `/tmp` or `/run` for a reason.